# Input signal rescaling block

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system

[image]

1. The input signal is limited and lies in range $[-U;+U]$. $U$ - unknown.
2. The output signal must be rescaled to be in the range $[-1;+1]$, i.e. is $+1$ if the input is at steady-state $+U$, and $-1$ if the input at steady-state $-U$.
3. Between $-1$ and $+1$ the output signal must also occupy some rescaled value.

What can be used as a block $ ??? $ for such a conversion? Is there a linear / non-linear filter that does this, and such and which is described by the differential equation?

*Remarks:*
*Red line, just my fantasy about how the input signal changes*

Comment: You could use $y[k] = u[k]/U[k]$ where $U[k] = \max(U[k - 1], u[k])$. This will be wrong at the start but if that is acceptable it would be a simple solution that will be correct once the steady state value is reached for the first time.

Comment: @SampleTime Good idea at first glance. Is there a continuous analogue of your proposal?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe you can convert it to continuous time. But this is maybe difficult because it is a nonlinear equation.

Comment: @SampleTime https://ibb.co/dK4cTPX

Or maybe there is some trick that allows using the input signal and its sign to get at the output a signal of the same shape, but scaled?

$+- 1/2$ is just my fantasy. :)

Comment: I don't see how you would use the sign to identify the steady state value of $1/2$ in your image. The sign doesn't tell you anything new about the steady state value (except its sign of course).

Comment: @SampleTime

I mean, is it possible to somehow use some kind of formula based on a function and its sign to get what is in the picture.

Comment: If you know the function in advance then maybe, but this would be a very different scenario than what you described in your question. Please clarify what you actually mean. Your picture also doesn't make much sense, why would you even need the sign? In your picture you seem to know from the very beginning what the steady state value is, so looking at the sign seems pointless?